# Error Importing 3rd party js lib in Stencil JS (ion-js)

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I am trying to import [ion-js](https://github.com/amazon-ion/ion-js) in Stencil-JS Component. I can get the same code to work in a React workspace but due to module it dosent seem to work in Stencil

```
componentWillLoad() {
    let ionData = `{ ccp_datatype_name:ResponsiblePerson, ccp_datatype_version:"1.0", definition:type::{ name: PriceSchema, major_version:1, minor_version:0, base:VariantBase, fields:[ { name:category, type:symbol, nullable:false, min_occurs:1, max_occurs:1 }, { name:address_identifier, type:string, nullable:false, min_occurs:1, max_occurs:1 } ] }, status:active, table_name:ccp_datatypes}`;
    let value = ion.load(ionData);
    console.log(value.fields())
  }
```

This same code works in run kit / React but not in stencil

```
require("jsbi/package.json"); // jsbi is a peer dependency. 
var ionJs = require("ion-js")
let ionData = `{ ccp_datatype_name:ResponsiblePerson, ccp_datatype_version:"1.0", definition:type::{ name: PriceSchema, major_version:1, minor_version:0, base:VariantBase, fields:[ { name:category, type:symbol, nullable:false, min_occurs:1, max_occurs:1 }, { name:address_identifier, type:string, nullable:false, min_occurs:1, max_occurs:1 } ] }, status:active, table_name:ccp_datatypes}`;


let value = ionJs.load(ionData);


console.log(value.fields());
```

#### Code Reproduction URL

https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-in-stencil-and-ion-js-6uzg1w

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'IonTypes')
    at Blob.js:6:36
    at createCommonjsModule (utils.ts:3:1)
    at Lob.js:58:1 undefined
```